How to preview iframe in a Flutter web app without CORS issues?
I am building a Flutter web application where I need to display previews of multiple badge links for each user. Each user can have multiple badge links, which may include:

Images (e.g., PNG, JPEG, SVG)
PDFs
Website links

My goal is to show previews of these badges inside a widget within the app. I am considering using IframeElement to handle the previews, but I am still concerned about potential CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issues when embedding the content.
Here are the requirements:
The badges may be hosted on third-party servers or storage services.
I cannot directly modify the server hosting these badges to include CORS headers.
Would using IframeElement be a reliable solution for previewing all types of badge links (image, PDF, and website)? Are there any alternative approaches or best practices to handle this scenario effectively?
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
